# template program crashing during execution

Tags: c++, if-statement, doubly-linked-list, nullptr

I'm implementing Doubly Linked List in C++, using templates. As I'm trying my hands on templates.

```
template <class T>
class DList{
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;
    public:
        Dlist(){
            head = tail = nullptr;
        }       
        void addToHead(T el){
            Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>(el);
            if(head == nullptr){
                head = tail = newNode;
            }
            else{
                head -> prev = newNode;
                newNode -> next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
        } };
```

When using this addToHead(), the if condition is not executing. And the program crashes.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Why are so many people here trying to write templated classes and functions when they obviously could not write the non-templated  versions? It's just adding complexity that gets in the way of learning C++.

Comment: How do you know, that _the comparison for if is not executing_?

Comment: _when the if is changed to_ that's exactly the same as in the snippet before.

Comment: Yeah @OliverCharlesworth, I did some debugging using cout statements.

Comment: Here's how I did it - 
   `cout<<"\nHere before if";
   if(head == 0){
    cout<<"\nHere in in";
    head = tail = newNode;
   }`

Comment: And what value has head?

Comment: @manni66, head was 0. Because of the` DList()` constructor.

Comment: Unrelated: prefer to use `nullptr` over 0 when parking a pointer at NULL. It makes your code a bit easier to read.

Comment: The code shown is fine, so the problem has to be in code you haven't shown. Please provide a [mcve] showing exactly how you are using the list.

Comment: You thought it must be 0, but according to your code it isn’t. Use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you @manni66, found my mistake. Rectified it, now its working fine.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm learning how to use templates in C++, I see nothing wrong in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mistake was with the constructor function, it was just an typo. Because of which the `head` and `tail` pointers were not initializing and when the `head` pointer was compared against the `nullptr` in the if condition of the addToHead(), program was crashing.